# Create custom checkout using shopify checkout api

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I wanted to make a custom checkout with Shopify checkapi. I have a checkout form with custom details and the card details when customer places the order are as follows (JSON):

```
  POST /sessions HTTP/1.1
  Host: https://elb.deposit.shopifycs.com
  Content-Type: application/json
  Accept: application/json

  {
    "payment": {
     "amount": "100.00",
    "unique_token": "my-client-generated-idempotency-token",
    "credit_card":{
    "number": "1",
    "month": "12",
    "year": "2019",
    "verification_value": "123",
    "first_name":"John",
    "last_name":"Smith"
    }
  }
 }
```

I can not understand how can I send the data using a form. Please help me about the process.